# How to remove attribute using $(document).on() using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove style attribute which is created dynamically..

I tried this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#refresh', function () {
     alert('test button');  //alert is working
     $('#dialogClose').removeAttr("style");
 });
```

**Note**

> the both button `#refresh` and `#dialogClose` is created dynamically.

Comment: What is your problem? it work http://jsfiddle.net/1xr83tj6/

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.on`.. your code is completely Ok and should work. you **did not** *specify* what was the **problem**

Comment: you should use `console.log( $('#dialogClose').length )` to check if the element exists

Comment: @Mohammad both `#refresh` and `#dialogClose` created dynamically. so when I tried it was not working

Comment: @Liamneesan Also work for dynamically created elements. http://jsfiddle.net/1xr83tj6/1/

Comment: @vsync when run in the code directly in console `$('#dialogClose').removeAttr("style");` it is removing. But it is not removing when I run the page

Comment: Obviously the element you think is in the page, isn't in the page. investigate if you're doing the action *before* the element is in the *document*

Comment: @Liamneesan Is that code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` or `$(function() { ... });`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#refresh').on('click', '#refresh', function () {
        $('#dialogClose').removeAttr("name_of_your_attr");
    });
})
```

You should put this after your elements and your page ready to confirm the `click` event from your browser.

Comment: `$('#refresh").on('click', '#refresh', function () { ... });` won't do anything.

Comment: It's worked for me. Did you add the jquery library to your project?

Comment: I'm not the opening poster :) I don't think this can work as it will look for a `#refresh` element within another `#refresh` element. That second argument to `on()` should not be there.